# Limit output of `adb shell dumpsys alarm`

Tags: android, adb, alarmmanager

I want to use the `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to debug some alarms I'm setting but it is producing a huge amount of data is there any way to limit the output to just a certain app?

I tried this to no avail: `adb shell dumpsys com.mypackage`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to use the adb shell dumpsys alarm to debug some alarms I'm setting but it is producing a huge amount of data is there any way to limit the output to just a certain app?

No, but command line utilities like `grep` and `fgrep` can show you snippets of the output that refer to some string, such as your package name.

Comment: I'm aware of this but this just returns the matching line, using `adb shell dumpsys | grep com.mypackage`, it doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: @Emil: Use the appropriate switches on `grep` or `fgrep` to return more context (i.e., lines around the one that contains the match).

Comment: Ok cool never used that switch before, in the end it is something like this: `adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep -A 5 com.mypackage`. Thanks maybe you can add this to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

For me putting the whole shell command in quotes worked
something like this :

```
adb shell "dumpsys alarm | grep my.packagename"
```

or

```
adb shell "dumpsys alarm | fgrep my.packagename"
```

Answer (score 0):

`dumpsys` command only works for "services" which have `.Dump()` implemented. You can see the list of services with `service list` command. Also you could check if `adb logcat -s -b events <NameOfYourApp>:*` produces the data you are looking for. If nothing else works for you - then there is `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but it might help someone in the future. You can use this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm | find "zima"
```

Which zima was a part of my package name. So just replace it with your own package name.